# Javascript Date Time Picker - Default Time Value

Tags: javascript

I am using this script for a Javascript Date and Time picker.
http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker.htm

After a few modifications I have gotten everything to work as I'd like it to minus the default time.

By default, if a time is not selected from the drop down menus initiating the onChange event, the time defaults to the current time.  I need this to default to 12:00am.  I Have looked through the code and have tried several changes but cannot get this to work the way I'd like.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: invalid url on your q.